# Gekko cspline function for FOPDT model (Dead-time) simulation

Tags: python, process, gekko, timedelay, cubic-spline

To simulate the dead-time in the FOPDT model using the GEKKO package, I used the Gekko 'cspline' function to make the time-shifting operation smoother.
It works well when the input changes after the length of dead-time. (eg. The input changes at t=15 when dead-time=10)
[image]

However, when the input changes before the length of dead-time (eg. The input changes at t=5 when dead-time=10), it looks like the cspline function overly extrapolates the input value. Please give some suggestions to avoid this problem.
[image]

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf = 50 
npt = 51 
t = np.linspace(0,tf,npt)
u1 = np.zeros(npt)
u1[5:] = 5

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = t 
time = m.Var(0)
m.Equation(time.dt()==1)

K1 = m.FV(1,lb=0,ub=1);      K1.STATUS=1
tau1 = m.FV(5, lb=1,ub=300);  tau1.STATUS=1
theta1 = m.FV(10, lb=2,ub=30); theta1.STATUS=1

uc1 = m.Var(u1) 
tc1 = m.Var(t) 
m.Equation(tc1==time-theta1)
m.cspline(tc1,uc1,t,u1,bound_x=False)

yp1 = m.Var()
m.Equation(yp1.dt() == -yp1/tau1 + K1*uc1/tau1) 

m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()

print('K1: ', K1.value[0])
print('tau1: ',  tau1.value[0])
print('theta1: ', theta1.value[0])
print('')

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u1)
plt.legend([r'u1'])
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,yp1)
plt.legend([r'y1'])
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.savefig('sysid.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If the dead-time is static then I recommend a discrete state space form instead. This is implemented as `m.delay()` in Gekko. Here are more details: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/TimeDelay and https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/DiscreteStateSpace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cspline object is given data for the range `t=0` to `t=50` but it accesses values for `t=-10` to `t=40`. The error is because of extrapolation from the cubic spline. You can generate spline data in the range `t=-theta_ub` to `t=50` to avoid extrapolation problems.

[image: Cspline extrapolation]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta_ub = 30
tf = 50

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = np.linspace(0,tf,tf+1)
time = m.Param(m.time)

K1 = m.FV(1,lb=0,ub=1)
tau1 = m.FV(5,lb=1,ub=300)
theta1 = m.FV(10,lb=2,ub=theta_ub)

u_step = [0 if ti<=5 else 5 for ti in m.time]
uc1 = m.Var() 
tc1 = m.Var()
m.Equation(tc1==time-theta1)

# for cspline
t1 = np.linspace(-theta_ub,tf,500)
u1 = [0 if ti<=5 else 5 for ti in t1]
m.cspline(tc1,uc1,t1,u1,bound_x=False)

yp1 = m.Var()
m.Equation(tau1*yp1.dt()+yp1==K1*uc1) 

m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()

print('K1: ', K1.value[0])
print('tau1: ',  tau1.value[0])
print('theta1: ', theta1.value[0])
print('')

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t1,u1,label='Unshifted Input')
plt.plot(m.time,uc1,label='Shifted Spline')
plt.xlim([0,tf])
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,yp1)
plt.legend([r'y1'])
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.savefig('sysid.png')
plt.show()
```